# 12V lamp has current with volt meter but bulb does not light

Tags: electrical, lamp

I have an Ikea Farja 12V desk lamp which does not light the bulb. I tried a few bulbs and they did not light so I tested the voltage with the probe in the sockets and it showed 12V. I then connected the voltmeter probes to the the pins on a known good bulb (voltmeter is not used) and it did not light i.e. the probes show voltage but will not light the bulb. To me it doesn't add up.

thoughts,
Eric

Edit: Thanks for the comments and I think this photo may help clarify. The probes are in the sockets and when connected to a voltmeter it registers 12V. When the other end of the probes are connected to the pins of the bulb as in the photo a known good bulb does not light.
[image]

Comment: Possible the centre post in the light socket is down too far and not contacting the light bulb.  Remove the power and gently pull up the centre post a tiny bit.

Comment: Connecting the Voltmeter to a disconnected bulb will certainly show nothing, as it's not connected.

Comment: Is the bulb supposed to be incandescent or LED? What's the resistance across its terminals both ways?

Other than that I'd suspect bad contact between the socket and the bulb, since you say voltage is present at the socket ... or the wrong bulb, expecting a different voltage.